# Assign a value to a df$column from another df?

Tags: r

Example:
I have a df in which the first column is

```
dat <- c("A","B","C","A")
```

and then I have another df in which I have in the first column is:

```
dat2[, 1]
[1] A B C
Levels: A B C

dat2[, 2]
[1] 21000 23400 26800
```

How can I add the values in the second df (`dat2`) to the first df (`dat`)?
In the first df there are repetitions and I want that everytime there is an "A" it will add the corresponding value (21000) from the second df in a new column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generating reproducible dataframe...

```
dat1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("A","B","C","A"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat2 <- data.frame(x1 = c("A","B","C"),
                   x2 = c(21000, 23400, 26800), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then use the `match` function.

```
dat1$dat2_vals <- dat2$x2[match(dat1$x1, dat2$x1)]
```

It is important to transform your character columns to `character` type rather than `factor` type or the elements will not match. I mention this due to the `levels` attribute in your dat2.

Answer (score 3):

A third option which I prefer is `left_join` from `dplyr`... It seems to be faster than `merge` with large data frames.

```
require(dplyr)

dat1 <- data.frame(x1 = c("A","B","C","A"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat2 <- data.frame(x1 = c("A","B","C"),
                   x2 = c(21000, 23400, 26800), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat1 <- left_join(dat1, dat2, by="x1")
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's race large dataframes with `microbenchmark`, just for fun!

**create large dataframes**

```
dat1 <- data.frame(x1 = rep(c("A","B","C","A"), 1000), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat2 <- data.frame(x1 = rep(c("A","B","C", "D"), 1000),
                   x2 = runif(1,0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**on your marks, get set, GO!**

```
library(microbenchmark)
mbm <- microbenchmark(
  left_join = left_join(dat1, dat2, by="x1"),
  merge = merge(dat1, dat2, by = "x1"),
  times = 20
)
```

Many, many seconds later.... left_join is **MUCH** faster for large dataframes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `merge` function.

```
# Input data
dat  <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "A"))
dat2 <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                   value = c(1, 2, 3))
# Merge two data.frames by specified column
merge(dat, dat2, by = "ID")
  ID value
1  A     1
2  A     1
3  B     2
4  C     3
```